# How to prove the following inequality: $1+ac+ab+3a\leq b+c+abc+3bc$?

Tags: inequality

Show that
$$1+ac+ab+3a\leq b+c+abc+3bc$$
if $1\leq a\leq bc,$ $1\leq b\leq ac,$ $1\leq c\leq ab.$

Comment: Where is the inequality from?

Answer (score 9):

$1\leq a$, so $0\leq (a-1)$. Similarly for $b$ and $c$, so we have

$$
0\leq (a-1)(b-1)(c-1)
$$

$a \leq bc$ so $0\leq bc-a$ and

$$
0 \leq 4(bc-a)
$$

Adding these two we get

$$
0 \leq (a-1)(b-1)(c-1) + 4(bc-a)
$$

Multiplying out yields the result:

$$
0 \leq (abc-ab-ac+a-bc+b+c-1) + 4bc - 4a
$$
$$
0 \leq abc-ab-ac-3a+3bc+b+c-1 
$$
$$
1+ab+ac+3a \leq abc+3bc+b+c
$$
As required.

To solve this I took out the $bc$ and $a$ terms, as given that $bc-a$ could be 0, I reasoned that the inequality should hold with them gone. I "guessed" the factorization $(a-1)(b-1)(c-1)$, and put in some extra terms to compensate, which happened to be of the form $bc-a$.

Comment: Nice job of exposing the symmetric heart of the question.